# Can't pass object from Nuxt.js page to Vue component with prop. Undefined prop variable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am unable to send data object from Nuxt.js page to a Vue component.

Get an error of `Cannot read property 'company' of undefined` in component file. So my prop of `experience` is not being defined. What am I missing?

Nuxt page  index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ExperienceItem
      v-for="experience in resume.experiences"
      :key="experience.id"
      v.bind:experience="experience"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ExperienceItem from '~/components/ExperienceItem'
export default {
  components: {
    ExperienceItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      resume: {
        name: 'Steve',
        title: 'Software Engineer',
        experiences: [
          {
            id: 1,
            company: 'Tech',
            title: 'Software Engineer',
            dates: 'Aug. 2014 - Mar. 2015'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            company: 'Tech',
            title: 'Software Engineer',
            dates: 'Aug. 2014 - Mar. 2015'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

ExperienceItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-card>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="4" class="text-right">
          <h3>{{ experience.company }}</h3>
          <h5>{{ experience.dates }}</h5>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ExperienceItem',
  props: ['experience']
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're making a typo here `v.bind:experience="experience"` which should be `v-bind:experience="experience"`

Comment: Omg. Thank you. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you made a typo with the usage of the `v-bind` directive. Instead of `v-bind` you typed in `v.bind`. To avoid such typos in the future you could use the shorthand `:` instead of `v-bind`(as you were rightfully doing with `:key`). So your template code would read as:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ExperienceItem
      v-for="experience in resume.experiences"
      :key="experience.id"
      :experience="experience"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```